# What is the correct way of loading the static template tag in Django?

Tags: django, static

The documentation is a bit ambiguous..

In https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files it says

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

and in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#template-tags it says

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

(some of our templates just have `{% load static %}` although I'm not sure if that is actually working..?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ways are correct.  But I always use `{% load staticfiles %}`.

`{% static %}` is the only tag in the `staticfiles` library so I don't see any reason to use the `{% load static from staticfiles %}` version.

As for the `{% load static %}` - this is a [built-in template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#static) which has no relation with the `staticfiles` contrib app.  If you don't use (and don't plan to use) any special [`STATICFILES_STORAGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_STORAGE) then this version will work for you just fine.

Comment: What about `{% load static %}`?

Comment: See the updated answer. Anyway I suggest to use the `{% load staticfiles %}` version.